# Архитектура web torrent клиента

Tags: java, spring-mvc, архитектура, torrent

Подскажите как правильно организовать локальную торрент качалку с веб интервейсом. Сам торрент клиент уже написан. Осталось прикрутить веб. Стоит ли ради "такого" дела поднимать спринг или же есть альтернативные пути? Если стоит прикрутить спринг, насколько подходит архитектура mvc?

Торрент клиент на вход получает файл.torrent(или же путь к файлу) и путь для сохранения. С возможностью выдачи статистических данных. Никакой безопасности и многопользовательности.

Comment: Ответов то и нет... Отметьте причину как "не уделили внимания"

Comment: @СергейГрушин эмм а как это тут проделать? При редактировании ничего подобного не наблюдается

Comment: ну значит поздно, это я вообще, на будущее )

Comment: @Nofate да вот мне показалось что спринг поднимать для этих дел уж очень шикарно, все равно что БелАЗ для перевозки картошки. Вот и хотелось услышать мнения более опытных

Comment: Железо самое простое которое можно представить ) orange pi с 1 гигом на борту

Comment: Простите, а чем вам не угодил готовый Transmission с его веб мордой?
Можно вообще без морды обойтись, используя RPC им можно вертеть как угодно: добавлять торренты, контролить скачивание, получать любые статистические данные простейшими HTTP запросами. Или у вас стоит конкретная задача "создать торрент качалку от и до"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А в чем сомнения возникли? Вам же по сути надо сделать CRUD для управления торрентами. Любой MVC тут подойдет. Но можно и без него. Архитектурно у вас уже есть разделение на UI и саму качалку.

Если у вас нет конкретных требований к аппаратным ресурсам делать можно на чем нравится.

Варианты:

- если хочется клиентскую часть сделать максимально тонкой - Spring Boot, Spring MVC, любой шаблонизатор (JSP, Thymeleaf, Velocity).
- если хочется попробовать SPA, то какой-нибудь не слишком тяжелый сервер (Jetty, Undertow, Ratpack) и JAX-RS обвязка для REST (Jersey, RESTeasy), или даже вовсе без нее, а UI ваять на JS.
- если хочется SPA без JavaScript, то можно попробовать GWT (Google Web Toolkit), но это путь в никуда.
- если все же железо слабое, и хочется чего-то с минимальным footprint, то лучше вообще отказаться от Java, а попробовать Python или даже Lua. Под них тоже достаточно как полноценный MVC, так минималистичных микро-web-фреймворков.